# Possible to use textures with different uv-maps on the same object (same faces, different seams)? [Game engine]

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to put different textures on an object, one for a better shading and one for markings (the object is a horse model). 
I want to keep the UV orientation of the shading texture I already have rendered but use a different one for the markings since I don't want to have some of the seams where they are on the shading-texture. 
 I already packed the one of them into the .blend file, as a thought that like this the UV is still loaded correctly for this one. 
Is it safe to use a second UV map now or is something that I need to pay attention to first? I don't want to re-render the whole texture since my computer is not the fastest. 
I hope, someone can help me here.

Comment: You can use multiple UV maps per mesh, and you can arbitrarily assing any of them to any texture independently of the others. Just go to the *Properties Window > Object Data > UV Maps*, and press the `+`button to add a new one. Packing textures is used for file transfer convenience, it has no effect on UV maps used.

Comment: okay thank you, then I know what to do now (=